# How to filter a nested column of type string in a dataframe using PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a nested column of type string in a dataframe and I am trying to filter on it based on non null values
install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields: string (nullable = true)  and I am getting an error on type mismatch when I run this. How can I filter a null value and an empty string " " for this nested column ?
..

```
df = spark.read.parquet('s3a:/tmp/data/*')

df.filter((df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields) 
& 
(df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields != "NULL") 
& 
(df.app_id == "620368452179218513") & (df.organization_id == "188876"))
df.count()
```

Comment: `df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields != "NULL"` this is not a way to compare nulls in pyspark.
You can use `Column.isNull / Column.isNotNull`:

`df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNull())

df.where(col("dt_mvmt").isNotNull())`

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things to check -

Use F.lit() where there is a String to validate
Use , F.col() instead of using DF.col()

The first condition There is nothing happening, nothing is being filtered

> df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields)

The modified version -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.filter(
(F.col("install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields")) & (F.col("install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields").isNotNull()) & 
(F.col("app_id") == F.lit("620368452179218513")) & 
(F.col("organization_id") == F.lit("188876")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add correct condition

```
df.filter((df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields) & 
          (df.install_activity_touch_data_additional_data_custom_fields.isNotNull()) &
          (df.app_id == "620368452179218513") & (df.organization_id == "188876"))

df.count()
```

Comment: Thanks, isNotNull() doesnt seem to work as it reports an error with undefined null. The rest seems to work fine.